# Redux and redux toolkit having problem without using createslice

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I wanted to ask can't we just simply use handwritten reducer in redux-toolkit as same as we use in redux js And then the rest of all thing I may keep according to tp redux-toolkit in store, but I don't how would I able to give initialState in configureStore please guide me I want to use same reducer function of redux handwritten instead of using createslice

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do that, and you can pass `preloadedState` into `configureStore` (although your hand-written reducer should have it's own "default state", as part of the method signature like `function myReducer(state = initialState, action) { ... }`).

But I'd seriously ask you to reconsider. There might be a one-off case where a hand-written reducer has so specific logic that the hand-written reducer actually makes sense, but in 99% of the cases, `createSlice` reduces the amount of code (often by a factor of 2-4), and it also makes a lot of common errors like accidentally mutating state impossible (in a hand-written reducer, that is not allowed and considered a bug, in a `createSlice` reducer it is totally okay and will lead to an implicit immutable update).

What is the exact reason why you don't want to use `createSlice`?

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your time actually sir i am just moving from redux to redux-toolkit actually i still use redux and very comfortable but i face some time problems while giving the state in hand written reducer,like today i was making it and i thought i would need to give object state as data was coming through id but when i gave product :{} to state it gave me blank page then i had to give loading:true, then it worked. These arw some things because of that i want to move towards redux-toolkit but dont know i would i use createslice i just want ti keep 95% things as same as in redux

Comment: Also sir can you please tell me with an example of handwritten code of reducer that i can use in configurStore, in that an array coming from data base please

Comment: You can use *every* old hand-written Redux reducer just like you did before with Redux Toolkit. It is hard to give an example of how that works, because it works.. just the same, there is no difference - assuming you did it right before. You would have to share what you are trying and doesn't work for you so you can get help. Also, please read [this tutorial chapter on modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to understand why you should not write any new Redux reducers without `createSlice`. You don't need all that boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank u very much you helped alot may you have all blessings